# Meromorphic function on projective plane and complex torus

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I'm attempting to do the following questions from Miranda's Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces.

Question II.2.A - 
Consider the projective line $\mathbb{P}^1$. Fix a point $p \in \mathbb{P}^1$, and a finite set $S \subset \mathbb{P}^1$ with $p \not \in S$. Show that there exists a meromorphic function $f$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$ with a simple at $p$ and no zeroes or poles at any of the points of $S$.

Question II.2.H - Consider the complex torus $X = \mathbb{C}/L$. Fix a point $p \in X$, and a finite set $S \subset X$ with $p \not \in S$. Show that there exists a meromorphic function $f$ on $X$ with a simple zero at $p$ and no zeroes or poles at any of the points of $S$.

I've been able to do the other questions, but am unsure of how to prove that there actually exists meromorphic functions with these properties.

Comment: Have you considered Riemann-Roch?

Comment: @SpamIAm I want to prove the result without Riemann-Roch

Comment: For the projective line, this is not difficult. There exists a meromorphic function $x$ such that it has a simple zero at 0 and a simple pole at $\infty$. So, you can consider the meromorphic function $R(x)$, $R$ a rational function in $x$ and check its poles and zeroes to obtain what you want. For the torus, one way would be to use Weierstrass $\wp$ function, if that is allowed.

Comment: I think Miranda introduces function theory on the torus via Jacobi theta functions rather than the Weierstrass theory, but the same idea should apply.

Comment: @Mohan How do we guarantee the condition on the sets $S \subset X$?

Comment: @Mohan I think if we use Weierstrass function, we cannot avoid the existence of poles.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p=(p_{0}:p_{1})$. We consider $a=(a_0:a_1)\in\mathbb{P}^1-(S\cup\{p\})$. Then,
$$
f=\frac{p_1 X_0-p_0 X_1}{a_1 X_0-a_0 X_1}
$$ 
is a rational function on $\mathbb{P}^1$ with a simple zero at $p$ and no zeros or poles at any of the points of $S$.

I guess that the same idea can be applied for the torus with theta functions.

Comment: Could you show how this applies to torus?